# Gaussian distribution

Tags: matlab, random, plot, gaussian

I want a MATLAB program for generating `n` random numbers assuming a Gaussian distribution, given the following inputs:

- 2 means (for x and y axis)
- standard deviation
- variances (covariance matrix = standard deviation x identity matrix)

Comment: What's your question? This sounds like it could be a request for us to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 5):

Another word for Gaussian distribuation is Normal distribution. Multidimensional is also sometimes called Multivariate. 
Therefore see: [Multivariate Normal Distribution in Matlab](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/stats/multivariate-normal-distribution.html).

Comment: +1 for the explanation of terms.

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't have access to the statistics toolbox, you can create pairs `(x,y)` of normally distributed data using `randn`

```
%# create an array of 100 pairs of normally distributed
%# coordinates with mu=0 and sigma=1

xy = randn(100,2);

%# transform the data such that means equal mu
%# and standard deviations equal sigma (no cross-correlation)

mu = [3,25]; %# means for x, y
sigma = [9,1]; % standard deviations for x,y

xy = bsxfun(@times,xy,sigma); %# fix standard deviation
xy = bsxfun(@plus,xy,mu); %# fix means
```